# Не останавливается воспроизведение

Tags: java, android, аудио

Программа должна начать цикличное воспроизведение звука при нажатии на кнопку. Звук должен остановиться когда будет нажата другая кнопка. Звук положил в assets

```
int cancel = -1;
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
descriptor = assetManager.openFd("cancel.ogg");
cancel = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);
```

На первую кнопку повесил обработчик с методом

```
soundPool.play(cancel, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
```

На вторую кнопку:

```
soundPool.stop(cancel);
```

В результате при нажатии на первую кнопку начинается бесконечное воспроизведение (как и требовалось). Но при нажатии на вторую кнопку воспроизведение не останавливается. Не пойму почему. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не много путаете идентификаторы потока и ресурса. Нужно взять Stream ID, а не Sound ID. Почитайте подробнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#play(int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float))

```
int streamID = soundPool.play(cancel, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);

soundPool.stop(streamID);
```

Правильнее будет делать так

```
int soundId = -1;
int streamId = -1;

SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
descriptor = assetManager.openFd("cancel.ogg");
soundId = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);


// on play
streamId = soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);

// on Stop
soundPool.stop(streamId);
```

Comment: теперь работает